# Submersible pump won't start

Tags: electrical, plumbing, pump, well-pump

My submersible pump stopped working suddenly. It's a 1.5hp pump 3 wire with a Franklin Electric control box and Irritrol pump start relay. I've measured across all 3 pump leads while out of circuit and they test fine (low resistance). On the control box, I have 230V in(red and black are both hot) and the start line is also hot. However, on the pump out, only the black leg is hot. Red has nothing. At the relay, the control line is hot but there is no voltage at either input or output. So, I replaced run and start capacitors (put a meter on it and they didn't appear to charge). I still have nothing at the red.

What's next in my troubleshooting?

Comment: Are you measuring phase to phase or phase to ground ? Any chance a breaker tripped and you're getting feed back on the red instead of line voltage?

Comment: Welcome to "why I have a two-wire pump" - I don't think 3-wire has made sense for decades. Not knowing what the wiring in your control box is supposed to look like, I'm still fairly clear that not having power on the input of the relay is a problem, and I seriously doubt it's a problem that new capacitors were going to solve. I do sort of wonder if you have a pressure switch with a low-pressure cutout to stop the pump running dry, which has shut down the pump power at the pressure switch (typically needs to be held until pressure builds.)

Comment: @lamengineer - Phase to phase. Hooked up a amp meter and drawing about 6A on start winding and run winding. No breaker tripped. Beginning to think the pump motor is locked up as the water is pretty hard.

Comment: Do you have a wiring diagram for your pump controls? If so, can you post it here?